# Indexes and array of maps in Firestore

Tags: firebase, indexing, google-cloud-firestore

I want to be sure that no, or very little, Firestore storage is used for indexing an array containing many maps. To my understanding when reading about [Firestore index types](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/index-overview), no index are created for array of maps in a document since that can not be queried. Am I right think this?

For example, here is an image of the array of maps:

[image]

There will be a lot of map elements in those progressionArray arrays but not enough to exceed 1MB per document. Since all progression data always needs to be loaded by the user, it seems best to me to store this data in an array to minimize Firestore reading costs (and index storage costs). Also there is no need to index this data since it will always all be loaded once by the user.

What are the indexing storage costs associated to this progressionArray? Are they zero like I think since it can not be queried?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/concepts/index-overview#single-field_indexes) says
“A single-field index stores a sorted mapping of all the documents in a collection that contain a specific field.” so indexes will be created for arrays of maps.

You can create an exemption for single field indexes as explained [here](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/query-data/indexing#exemptions).

The only cost the indexes have is the amount of storage it takes to save them. You can calculate the index cost with the values specified in this [document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/storage-size#single-field_index_entry_size).